# Can screen add nl (new-line) for each (carriage-return)

Tags: gnu-screen

Edited:
I have data acquisition hardware that sends out serial data via UART into FTDI (serial to USB) device.  The FTDI is plugged into USB port and its port name is `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  This device outputs data in the following format:

```
data line 1\r
data line 2\r
...
data line n\r
```

I tried using screen to view the data by entering the following command:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

The screen begins to show all data on one line, so I see a single line flashing.  How can I add a newline character at the end of each line so that the screen begins to separate the lines?

Original:
I am using a serial device that terminates lines with just carriage return.  Is it possible to configure screen to add a nl (new-line) character for every cr character?

Thanks...

EDIT: Was not able to get this working with screen, picocom works great.  I use the following command `picocom -b 115200 --imap crcrlf /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: It isn't clear what problem you're trying to solve.  Depending on what you want to do, you can use `minicom(1)` to talk to your device, set `eol` character for the line discipline with `stty(1)`, configure `getty(1)`, etc.

Comment: OK, so my device sends a line via `/dev/ttyUSB0` with with format `"this is the line\r"`, is it possible to have screen convert it to `"this is the line\r\n"` or `"this is the line\n\r"`  I do not care about the order, I just need a newline for every carriage return.  Thanks...

Comment: Yes, you already said that.  Who / what application talks to your device and how?  Is it a terminal?  A modem?  A data aquisition device?  A camera?  A printer?  An unicorn with an USB interface? :)

Comment: It is a data acquisition device that sends out data via 3 wire UART into FTDI (UART to USB chip), the port name of the FTDI device is /dev/ttyUSB0.

Comment: Ok, so how do you read from it?  Just `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`?  Point being: there should be some kind of application that sits between `/dev/ttyUSB0` and your terminal.

Comment: I use `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`, Sorry, I was not sure how to ask the question...

Comment: Then your `screen` is not [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) as most people here would assume, but some other terminal emulator.  There should be some configuration options for it to let you set endline mode.  You might also try using `minicom(1)` instead of this `screen`.

Comment: @lcd047 actually, it's a [little known feature of screen](http://askubuntu.com/a/40970) (that I also didn't know about). I've removed my answer while I chew on a good response.

Answer (score 7):

I know this isn't answering the exact question you have, but I normally jump to `miniterm.py` when presented with this kind of device because I've never found a way to do what you want with screen.

`miniterm.py` is minimal like screen and does the 'right thing' by default with `\n`. On the downside, my fingers don't know how jump around, quit and log, etc, so I still live in hope there's a way to do the right thing in `screen`

On OS X:

```
miniterm.py /dev/tty.usbmodem1412
```

gives me nice output when screen would have scrawled all over the place.

[pySerial](http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyserial.html) comes with `miniterm.py` as far as I understand